# How to download extracted data from Schema Markup Validator

Tags: java, web-scraping, web-crawler, schema, schema.org

I want to crawl and collect information about products and their prices from some e-commerce websites like Walmart or Target, and I found using [Schema Markup Validator](https://validator.schema.org/) or [Google's Rich Result Test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) to extract structured data like price, description, etc would be easier than searching for attributes in HTML with xpath etc. However I don't know how to download the extracted data so that I can integrate it in my Java code.
Or better, is there any way I can program this in Java with the help of these schema testing tools?

Comment: So you can use the Selenium for the same result?

Comment: @LuậnNguyễnMinh I have to manually search for the attributes with xpath functions but some websites don't use the same class names or attributes. I think with schema validator they make the field names the same at least, so it'd be easier to extract the needed info from there.

Comment: @NganNguyen to extract data from Schema validators you need to extract it with xpath or css or pw selectores as you said **"searching for attributes in HTML"**, but do it from validator page and not from product.